# xdg-user-dirs-update not working with more than one directory

Tags: xdg-user-dirs

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/xdg-user-dirs-update.1.html

Why is only the last directory being set in the `xdg-user-dirs` file?

```
% xdg-user-dirs-update --dummy-output ~/test \
  --set DOCUMENTS $HOME/Apples \
  --set MUSIC $HOME/Bananas \
  --set PICTURES $HOME/Oranges \
  --set VIDEOS $HOME/Pears

% cat ~/test
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
#
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Pears"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% cat ~/.dotfiles/config/.config/user-dirs.dirs
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR=
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR=
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR=
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR=
XDG_MUSIC_DIR=
XDG_PICTURES_DIR=
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR=
```

It seems that you need to change each directory separately and it only updates variables that are already there (or otherwise just the last directory), so you need to have at least the empty variables you want already in the file, as shown above.

I was trying to script automated setup for when Windows WSL is being used and this is what I ended up with:

```
# Set xdg-user-dirs
xdg-user-dirs-update \
  --dummy-output ~/.dotfiles/config/.config/user-dirs.dirs \
  --set DOCUMENTS $WIN_HOME/Documents
xdg-user-dirs-update \
  --dummy-output ~/.dotfiles/config/.config/user-dirs.dirs \
  --set MUSIC $WIN_HOME/Music
xdg-user-dirs-update \
  --dummy-output ~/.dotfiles/config/.config/user-dirs.dirs \
  --set PICTURES $WIN_HOME/Pictures
xdg-user-dirs-update \
  --dummy-output ~/.dotfiles/config/.config/user-dirs.dirs \
  --set VIDEOS $WIN_HOME/Videos
```

---

```
% cat ~/.dotfiles/config/.config/user-dirs.dirs
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
#
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/mnt/c/Users/jason/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/mnt/c/Users/jason/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/mnt/c/Users/jason/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/mnt/c/Users/jason/Videos"
```